# How to make sort less value from document using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is the `document_1.xml`

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document_2.xml` is

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
    </product> 

    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document.xml` is

```
<products>
</products>
```

Below is my xsl, i used to join `document_1.xml` and `document_2.xml` to the `document.xml`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_1.xml')/*/product"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_2.xml')/*/product"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need output like below

1. Sort by Quantity ASC
2. And Distinct `<name>` with minimum quanity

   ```
   <products>
       <product>
           <name>Bag</name>
           <Quantity>2</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pencil</name>
           <Quantity>5</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pen</name>
           <Quantity>10</Quantity>
       </product>
   ```

Comment: The output you have posted looks to me like the document_2.xml only so sorting a single document should be easy. Your text however says you want to join two documents. In what way exactly, do you want to add the quantities (so that for instance you get `<product><name>Pen</name><Quantity>40</Quantity></product>`)?

Comment: need to join two documents and take the best value. because some cause less price comes in first document

Comment: Please explain the criteria as to what is the "best" value. If there are two quantities for a product, which one do you want in the result document?

Comment: 1) I update the document_1.xml and document_2.xml.  2) i mean min quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kProdByName" match="product" use="name"/>

<xsl:variable name="vallProds" select=
 "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/document_1.xml')/*/*
 |
  document('file:///c:/temp/delete/document_2.xml')/*/*
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="vrtfProds">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vallProds">
    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    <xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:variable>

  <products>
   <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($vrtfProds)">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kProdByName', name)[1])]"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </products>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document** (could be document.xml, but this is not used), and having the two provided documents residing at: `c:\temp\delete\document_1.xml` and `c:\temp\delete\document_1.xml`,

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Sorting the `product` elements of the union of the two documents **by two keys**: `name` *and* `Quantity`.
2. Extracting the regular tree from the RTF (**[Result Tree Fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Result-Tree-Fragments)**) produced in step 1. above and performing **[Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** of `product` by `name`.

Answer (score 0):

**User this code for sorting**

```
<xsl:for-each select="products/product">
      <xsl:sort select="Quantity"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: like below its working <xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_1.xml')/*/product|document('document_2.xml')/*/product">
<xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample XSLT 1.0 making use of the `exsl:node-set` extension function most processors support:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

  <xsl:param name="doc1-url" select="'document1.xml'"/>
  <xsl:param name="doc2-url" select="'document2.xml'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($doc1-url)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($doc2-url)"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="product" use="name"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="joined-products">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$doc1//product | $doc2//product"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="grouped-products">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($joined-products)/product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', name)[1])]" mode="group"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($grouped-products)/product">
        <xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product" mode="group">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', name)">
          <xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Quantity>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i getting error : Namespace 'http://exslt.org/common' does not contain any functions.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? If that is MSXML then change `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` into `xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and then of course anywhere where I used `exsl:node-set` you need to use `ms:node-set`. And finally then use `exclude-result-prefixes="ms"`.