# How remove node from the document method using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

below is the `document_1.xml`

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document_2.xml` is

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
    </product> 

    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document.xml` is

```
<products>
</products>
```

Below is my xsl, i used to join `document_1.xml` and `document_2.xml` to the `document.xml`

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kProdByName" match="product" use="name"/>

<xsl:template match="products">
<xsl:copy>

<xsl:variable name="msNodes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_1.xml')/*/product|document('document_2.xml')/*/product">
    <xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="ns:node-set($msNodes)/product [generate-id() =  generate-id(key('kProdByName', name)[1])  ]"/>

</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="product">
   <product>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kProdByName', name)">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </product>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of above xsl is

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </product>
    </product>
```

here i need to remove `<Quantity>` node from the output using xslt 1.0

i need output like below

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
    </product>
    </product>
```

Comment: Plz check my xsl ... i update that .. in that case, how i remove node

Comment: What did you change and what do you want use to check? I don't see that you've added the empty Quantity template as suggested

Comment: @user475464: **This is not your xsl** -- this is *my* answer to your previous question, which you haven't upvoted or accepted -- as you ignored this and all other answers! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9364991/36305

Comment: sure.. its ur answer... Mr. Dimitre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::Quantity)]"/>
```

Or, if `Quantity` isn't a direct child of `product`, but a descendant, then replace the above with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="skipQuantity"/>
```

and also add the following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="skipQuantity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="skipQuantity"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Quantity" mode="skipQuantity"/>
```

**Do notice**:

While these changes produce the new wanted result, a lot of the previous processing becomes unnecessary and can be omitted completely.

**The transformation can be simplified significantly to this** (no finding of minimum quantity, just grouping based on product name):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kProdByName" match="product" use="name"/>

    <xsl:template match="products">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="msNodes">
                    <xsl:copy-of select=
                    "document('document_1.xml')/*/product
                |
                     document('document_2.xml')/*/product"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:apply-templates select=
             "ns:node-set($msNodes)/product
                  [generate-id()
                  =
                   generate-id(key('kProdByName', name)[1])
                   ]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Quantity"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: above is working. if there <Quantity> is a sub node how to do this remove? for example <Details><Quantity>2</Quantity><Price>10</Price></Details>

Comment: I updated my answer, reflecting the latest new requirement. Please, remember to accept + upvote the answer(s) that solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

An empty template matching `Quantity` should do it:

```
<xsl:template match="Quantity"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<xsl:template match="/products/product/Quantity"/>
```