# How to remove node using self:: in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

for example below is the xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Amount><Price>2</Price><Currency>USD</Currency></Amount>
    </product> 
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
        <Amount><Price>2</Price><Currency>USD</Currency></Amount>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
        <Amount><Price>2</Price><Currency>USD</Currency></Amount>
    </product>
</products>
```

in my xsl i using like below to remove

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::Quantity)]"/>
```

I also need to remove sub node `<Currency>` from the `<Amount>`

i try like below

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::Quantity) and not(self::Amount/Currency)]"/>
```

but not working fine . it will remove all node's from `<Amount>`

How i remove sub node `<Currency>` only?

Comment: You haven't provided a complete XSLT transformation, nor have you provided the exact wanted result. Mentioning in the comments that you "can't use `<xsl:template/>` method " disqualifies this question from belonging to the "xslt" tag...

Comment: I agree with hon'  @DimitreNovatchev ..

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind': :) I just +1-ed your answer and one of your comments. Should I also call you "hon'", or will it have a different meaning? :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, thank you :) well. hon word doesn't suit rookies :) yes it does make a difference .. of a class :D

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Usage of C# script in XSLT file, I had learnt from you :) I use it heavily .. Indeed have suggested to many beginners .. and just now someone accepted it .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394322/xslt-1-0-get-current-datetime/9394846#comment11871922_9394846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `self`

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[self::Currency]"/>
```

or if you want to know other simpler way :)

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Currency"/>
```

The above templates copy all other tags except `<Currency>`

> EDIT: Replace the below code

```
<xsl:template match="product">
   <product>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kProdByName', name)">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </product>
</xsl:template>
```

By this: (hope it works)

```
  <xsl:template match="product">
    <product>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kProdByName', name)">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Currency|Quantity"/>
```

Comment: its a question from below link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367570/how-remove-node-from-the-document-method-using-xslt)

Comment: I try like this <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::Quantity) and not(self::Currency)]"/> but it is not removing the currency

Comment: i can't use <xsl:template/>  method

Comment: @user475464, who said you can't use `<xsl:template/>` its the base of XSLT :)

Comment: I try <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:if>
out put is coming blank

Comment: @user475464: Why would you try (g a s p ...) `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` -- didn't you proclaim that you "*can't use <xsl:template/>*" ? :)